# CS Information Systems Image Border

Tags: html

I nested my .ImageBorder inside of the style as follows:

```
<style>
.ImageBorder
{
border-width:1px;
border-color:Black;
}
div.ex
{
width:400px;
padding:10px;
border:5px solid gray;
margin:0px;
}
</style>
```

I am using image as such:

```
<img src="claude-shannon1.jpg" width="400" height="400" class = "ImageBorder"/>
```

Why does it not produce my intended results?

I compared the general syntax to simple text:

```
<div class="ex">Claude Shannon</div>
```

When used with the above div.ex works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must supply a `border-style`.

```
.ImageBorder
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
}
```

For future reference, you can quickly define a border in a shorthand form:

`border:1px solid black;`